# Using AngularJS $http Post to upload files

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, angularjs, office365apis

I have been working on file upload service for my project and everything is looking good except for the request. Works OK with jQuery.AJAX and appears to work with Angualr $http but the file is not readable.

Here is the AJAX

```
            return jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": getRequestDigest(),
                "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
            }
        });
```

And this is the Angular I that does not work.

```
            var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: arrayBuffer,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": getRequestDigest(),
                "Content-Length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
            }
        };

        $http(req).then(function (data) {
            log.Debug('data - 141', data, serviceId);
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }, function (error) {
            log.Debug('error - 144', error, serviceId);
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
```

thinking maybe someone has come across this before, specific to uploading files. I have $http requests for updating lists with no issues. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uploading file, AngularJs does not work in jQuery way! In earlier time, I had a R&D and made it working. Find below:

```
function fileUploadRequest(data, url) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: baseUrl + url,
                method: "POST",
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
                    "Content-Type": undefined
                }
            })
                .success(function (result) {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                })
                .error(function (result, status) {
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

## Following two things are very very important!

- `transformRequest: angular.identity`
- `"Content-Type": undefined`

  It is same as uploading file in ASP.NET MVC5 application. I had an article regarding that.

[File Upload Using AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC5](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/878730/File-Upload-Using-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC)